# PHP, функция isset(), нюансы в определении

Tags: php, документация

По мотивам [заведенного бага](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74890) (см. внизу секцию "comments")

[Ссылка на страницу документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php)

В английской документации сказано:

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

В русской переведено так:

> isset — Определяет, была ли установлена переменная значением отличным
>   от NULL

Автор багрепорта настаивает на исправлении перевода на следующий:

> isset — Определяет, была ли создана переменная и установлена значением
>   отличным от NULL

И все бы ничего, но в процессе дискуссии всплыло следующее:

> Именно в моей учебной группе пару учеников не смогли понять что isset
>   определяет что переменная была создана! И с точки зрения ЛОГИКИ они
>   правы.

И вот тут я впал в ступор. Мне кажется, что вопрос ушел в какую то совсем не ту степь, и упор на то, что `isset определяет что переменная была создана` несет скорее вред, чем пользу.

Собственно хочется услышать мнение профессионалов в PHP, это я дурак и ничего не понимаю или автору багрепорта хочется странного?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В PHP, `созданная переменная` - это такая, запись о которой присутствует в `symbol table`. Запись в `symbol table` появляется тогда, когда переменной присваивается значение (хоть бы и null).

Т.е. если рассуждать в контексте исполнения PHP-скрипта, `переменная создана` и `переменной присвоено значение` - по сути синонимы.

`isset` возвращает возвращает `false` в двух случаях:

1. Переменная равна `null`
2. Переменная отсутствует в `symbol table`

Фактически, `isset` возвращает `true`, если переменной было присвоено любое значение, кроме `null`, что и написано в текущем варианте страницы описания.

Т.е. предложенный вариант

> isset — Определяет, была ли создана переменная и установлена значением
>   отличным от NULL

по сути является маслом масляным, так как при исполнении PHP-скрипта, `была ли создана переменная` и `установлена значением` - означают одно и тоже, но при этом, переусложняют и запутывают определение.

Comment: На самом деле, что значит `была установлена`? То есть я должен ЗНАТЬ, что переменная уже создана. Также порой путается применение `isset` и `empty`.

Comment: @DaemonHK по поводу isset и empty вот тут почитайте мой ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/45389115/3231606 , с точки зрения кишок PHP - это две функции являющиеся зеркальным отражением друг друга

Answer (score -1):

Если Вы хотите установить значение переменной то isset здесь нипричем..
isset реагирует только на null, ведь если переменная ровняется null то какой смысл isset-у говорить что она есть..? Веть она неактивная.. она даже не пустая, а именно скрипт ее не воспринимает вообще...

```
 $text = null;

  if(isset($text){
  //переменной нет!
   }
```

isset стоит визывать только если переменной присвоено хоть какоето значетие

```
 $text = 'text';
```

Или как минимум нужно указать что она пустая:

```
 $text = '';
```

Пустую переменную isset видит (ведь она есть, просто пустая).
А вот переменную со значеним null нет.

Я просто не доконца понял Ваш вопрос..

Comment: А if роботает не наоборот а по другой системе при запросе (пример в ответе) в первых скобках из за значения null  переменная не будет определена, но если доставить else то оно будет игнорировать null и по этому говорит что переменная существует..

Comment: Ну вот тут вы совсем не правы. В PHP очень четкое разделение на `undefined` переменные и переменные равные `null`. Практически любая функция в первом случае среагирует выбросом ошибки `Undefined variable`, а во втором в зависимости от внутренней логики